# OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address when testing the sendtestemail of kiwi tcms

Tags: django, docker, kiwi-tcms

I am encountering this error below when running the command "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py sendtestemail user1@example1.tld":

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

I can't find other logs pertaining to this error.

The full error log:

```
File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sendtestemail.py", line 35, in handle
    send_mail(
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 80, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 337, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Is there a solution for this?